# Hadoop Counters—how do i use different type of counters?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My question is, how do I make counters where i can put stuff like doubles in them (yes, i did use LongValue but that gives me 0)?

Answer (score 4):

Hadoop MapReduce job counters are by definition Java `long` values.  A MapReduce job implementation can obtain a handle to a `Counter` through the `TaskAttemptContext`.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext.html#getCounter(java.lang.Enum)

After obtaining a handle to a `Counter`, the job can either increment the counter by a delta or set it to a specific value.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter.html#increment(long)

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter.html#setValue(long)

Notice that the method signatures all are specified in terms of `long`.  The domain model does not support usage of `double` or any other data type as a counter value.

If it's absolutely necessary, then you could come up with some creative way to encode your data type into a `long`.  One way to do this would be to take advantage of the fact that both `long` and `double` are 64 bits wide.  You could then use `Double#doubleToLongBits` to encode the `double` value as a `long`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)

However, the only way to make sense of this later would be to write custom code that unpacks that counter value after the job finishes and passes it to `Double#longBitsToDouble`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long)

This would be a very unusual usage of Hadoop MapReduce job counters though.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can do something like this

```
long convert = (long) (mydoubleVal * 10000);
context.getCounter(MyCounter.name1).setValue(convert);
```

And in Driver you can get the double values.

```
long c2 = job0.getCounters().findCounter(MyCounter.name1)
                    .getValue();
double getMyVal= (double) c2 / 10000;
```